# How to fetch key value pair from logger response

Tags: json, playframework-2.0, gson, log4javascript

I am using `log4javascript.js` to fetch the client side log messages on server side.
Response is coming as mentioned below but i am unable to find any solution to parse key value pair from the obtained response.

RESPONSE IS

```
DefaultRequestBody(Some(Map(data -> List([{"logger":"mylogger","timestamp":13898
81604787,"level":"ERROR","url":"http://<ipaddress>:9000/","message":"Error message
(appears in pop-up and in server log)"}]), layout -> List(JsonLayout))),None,No
ne,None,None,None,false)
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the log4javascript docs it uses a regular form post for each log entry by default so a good idea would be to use the play forms api to parse the post into some object of your liking. You can find the docs for Scala here http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaForms and for Java here http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/JavaForms